# Why is this error crashing the app instead of being caught and handled

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, bluebird

I am new to promises and playing around with them right now. I have created this basic application:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var express = require('express');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var app = express();

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {


    getStuffFromDb('my_password')
        .then((hash) => {
            console.log('hash = ' + hash);
            return hash; 
        })
        .then((hash) => {
            res.send(hash);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            errorHandler(error, res)
        });
});


function getStuffFromDb(password) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //This should fail because it is missing a parameter, a number to specify how many loops
        bcrypt.genSalt(function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(Error("It broke 1"));
            }
//This should cause an error as result_which_does_not_exist is not defined, and the call to the function should be bcrypt.hash(password, result_which_does_not_exist ...) so it is missing a parameter
            bcrypt.hash(result_which_does_not_exist, null, function(err, hash) { 
                if (err) {
                    return reject(Error("It broke 2"));
                } else {
                    return resolve(hash);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}


function errorHandler(error, res) {
    res.send(error.message);
}

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

So indie this function the application should fail at the generation of the salt because a parameter is missing. Instead it is failing at the hashing of the password because a parameter is missing and I have passed in a variable which does not exist. This is causing my server to crash with the following error:

```
bcrypt.hash(result_which_does_not_exist, null, function(err, hash) { ReferenceError: result_which_does_not_exist is not defined.
```

So the application is crashing, but I want this error to be handled, I do not want it to crash my server. How can I do this? I am very new to promises (about 1 hour into reading about them), but from my understanding the catch should have caught this?

Comment: @vp_arth sorry, but I do not see how this duplicate answer you posted applies here at all? The accepted answer's section on how to catch errors recommends domains which are now deprecated. I am using promises, and the promise is not capturing the result the way I am expecting.

Comment: @vp_arth I don't think this question should be marked as a duplicate? The duplicate specifies how to capture errors in nodejs, my question is regarding why this promise is not capturing. May you please explain how they are a duplicate as I see no relevance between the question what so ever?

Answer (score 1):

`bcrypt.hash` isn't catching the error and passing it into your callback, rather the runtime is throwing a reference error because `result_which_does_not_exist` is a variable which does not exist.

Give the variable a value to avoid the reference error! Or throw your code in a try/catch.

For example, this will throw a reference error:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    console.log(foo);
});
```

...

> Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: foo is not defined

This is what you'd need to do:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    try {
        console.log(foo);
    } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
});
```

But that's all moot – you should just fix the reference error :)

Comment: But what if it wasn't a reference error and for example say some other unexpected error occurred (some problem inside of the bcrypt library lets say). I don't think try catch would work with async function. I tried something like this now:try {
    setTimeout(function() {
       JSON.parse('{');
    }, 1000);
}
catch (e) {
    alert("This never gets printed!");
}. So if I wrap the async bcrcypt function in a try catch statement it doesn't seem like the catch would ever be executed.

Comment: If you wrap try/catch around code that simply *calls a function that immediately returns successfully* (async), you are correct that it would never catch an error. It's the job of the async logic's resolution handlers (success, failure, errors, exceptions, whatever) to handle itself properly and ultimately run your callback, handing it an error as the first parameter if it encountered one.

Comment: For the sake of conversation and this project that you're playing around with, assume bcrypt is flawless – it will **always** run your callback with or without an `err` parameter for you. In that world, your reference error is basically you tripping and hitting the floor before even calling bcrypt, and then wanting bcrypt to help you recover from it.

Comment: Please excuse me as I am not at all an expert in async/promises. So what you are saying is if I call the bcrypt.hash function and I am missing a parameter, it is then bcrypt who should return an error so then in function(err, hash) the err object should have an error such as 'missing param'? So in my case if I am missing a parameter and nothing is happening when it is called, there is really nothing I can do about it because it is bcrypt which is not returning an error?

Comment: No, I am saying the opposite. My apologies for not being clear. Think of this order of operations: (1) Your command to execute the function is interpreted by Node. (2) Node sees that you're passing in a variable that doesn't exist and throws a reference error which you are not catching (3) The bcrypt function runs. Bcrypt will handle any of its errors. You're causing an error to occur before your bcrypt function has executed.

Answer (score 0):

First the [documentation of bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) states that the first parameter of `bcrypt.genSalt` is optional. So this is why it is not failing at the generation of the salt.

Second the Promise catch should work properly. When I try it without bluebird it works. Why are you using bluebird when node.js has Promises built in?

Comment: [Bluebird performs better; also the "native" implementation in V8 is just Javascript.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird/279003#279003)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the first point, that makes sense then.  The code I provided doesn't crash the program, instead nothing happens (even though the catch method should be called and send a response back to the client at least this is what I think should be happening). If you add the parameter password into the bcrypt.hash function (1st param then the error I show in the question will appear). I need it to capture so I can send the error back to the client, otherwise the client is just waiting and has no idea an error occurred.